# CV - State third party agency job

Tags: resume, third-party

I was working with South Western Railway through Adecco for the past 2 years. Now, I have switched to South Western Railway themselves (without Adecco). How do I list that down on my CV?

Should I write

1. South Western Railway (normal) [Dates - To-date]
2. South Western Railway (through Adecco) [Dates]

Is that fine? Or is some other layout is suggested?

Comment: Did the job title or responsibilities change at all? Or just the name on your paycheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to mention the *"(normal)"* there, it's implicit, the rest is fine.

Comment: Simple, to the point, and more importantly - absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

You propose:

> Should I write
>
> 1. South Western Railway (normal) [Dates - To-date]
> 2. South Western Railway (through Adecco) [Dates]

But it is more accurate to format it as:

1. South Western Railway [Dates - To-date]
2. Adecco [Dates]

You do it this way because you were an employee of Adecco during that time, you were not an employee of South Western Railway until your present job.

Under each section you will describe your roles, responsibilities and accomplishments. In the Adecco section you may mention the company your contract supported, but you cannot claim to be an employee of that client.

It is not unusual to support multiple companies/organizations while working for a single contracting company, but you need to make it clear who was your employeer during that time period.